# How to implement "cryptseup isLuks" function using cryptsetup library APIs

Tags: linux, cryptsetup, dm-crypt

In shell script

```
$crypsetup isLuks /dev/sda1
```

Above command returns

- 0 -> for luks partition (encrypted partition)
- 1 -> non luks partitions (non encrypted partition).

I have implemented disk encryption using library APIs in CPP program.
How can i check whether a partition is luks partition or not using crypsetup APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`crypt_load`](https://mbroz.fedorapeople.org/libcryptsetup_API/group__crypt-actions.html#ga7af2ba4a33a3be8b1abc6248292f7b16) function to do that. Quick "reimplementation" of `cryptsetup isLuks` could look like this:

```c
#include <libcryptsetup.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEVICE "/dev/sda1"


int main (void) {
    struct crypt_device *cd = NULL;
    int ret;

    ret = crypt_init (&cd, DEVICE);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf ("Failed to initialize device\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    ret = crypt_load (cd, CRYPT_LUKS, NULL);
    crypt_free (cd);
    
    if (ret != 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return ret;
}
```

Note that `crypt_load` reads the entire LUKS metadata so if you only want to check the superblock to see if the device has a LUKS header, using libblkid might be better (and faster). For that you can check [this implementation](https://github.com/storaged-project/libblockdev/blob/2.x-branch/src/plugins/crypto.c#L426) of "is LUKS" in the [libblockdev library](http://storaged.org/libblockdev/).